# Spring Cloud - Configuration client caching properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

When I change a value from my properties repository and restart the Spring Cloud Config Server, the changes do not reflect on it's consumers.

**my-microservice/application.properties:**

```
spring.application.name=my-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

**MyServiceController.java**

```
@RestController
public class MyServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;

    @GetMapping("/my-service")
    public MyServiceBean retrieveMyServiceProperties() {
        // show propertie's values
        return new MyServiceBean(configuration.getPropertie1(), configuration.getPropertie2());
    }

}
```

**spring-cloud-config-server/application.properties**

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file://path
```

**Git repo**

*my-service.properties*

```
my-service.propertie1=1
my-service.propertie2=2
```

When I send a GET request to **localhost:8080/my-service**, that's the result I got:

```
{  
   "propertie1":1,
   "propertie2":2
}
```

Fine, that's OK!
But, if I change the `my-service.properties` and restart my Spring Cloud Config Server, the changes do **not** reflect `MyServiceController`. I do need to restart *my-microservice* application, for changes to take effect.
Is this the normal behavior? I mean, if this is remote, then, it should be configured whether to cache or not.

Comment: you shouldn't restart config server, but call the `/refresh` actuator endpoint on the client

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update the configurations, I sent a `POST` request to `localhost:8080/actuator/refresh`.

By default, `/refresh` isn't exposed in actuator endpoints.

I did exposed with the following line in application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Then, sent a `POST` request with **no** body to the endpoint above.

Comment: why it causes client application to restart whenever we hit /actuator/refresh endpoint

Answer (score 1):

To update your client application, It's better to use a message broker like RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka.
This process has three levels:

1. The client application and config server subscribe to a specific topic (**/refresh**) in the message broker.
2. The config server sends **refresh** event to that topic (**/refresh**), as soon as it gets updated. (for example application.properties file gets updated in git).
3. All client applications are listening to **refresh** event, when they get  refresh message, they will be updated

> In brief, we can use the **pub-sub** model for updating our client applications.

[Config Server using Spring Cloud Config and Apache Kafka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywrLJ.jpg)

[image: Spring cloud config workflow]